# Como converter String para Int em C++

Tags: c++, string, int

Não estou conseguindo converter este simples programa.. como que faz pra converter?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    int i;
    string a;

    i = atol (a);
}
```

.

Mensagem de erro:

```
Teste 1.cpp:12:16: error: cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'long int atol(const char*)'
     i = atol (a);
                ^
```

Comment: atol recebe um `const char*` como parametro. Se você deseja converter uma std::string para long int, use `stol()`.

Comment: A parte isso, você precisa inicializar essa string com algum valor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vários erros nesse código. A começar pelo include

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

`string` Não tem a extensão `.h`. Isso é de fato um pouco confuso, em C++ os headers das bibliotecas não possuem extensão, mas bibliotecas em C possuem. Quando você ver uma biblioteca com `.h`, ela provavelmente é uma biblioteca do C, se não tiver `.h`, é do C++. Como `string` é uma biblioteca do C++, lembre-se, ela não possui extensão.

```
i = atol(a);
```

Não deveria ser `atoi`? `ASCII to integer`? Mesmo assim essa função não irá funcionar, `atoi` é uma função do C. Lembra que `string` é uma biblioteca do C++? Não existem funções em C que recebem `string`, funções do C recebem `*char`, então você precisa primeiro converter essa `string` para `*char` com o método `a.c_str()`. Ou então utilizar `stoi`, `string to integer`.

Agora basta inicializar a sua string, afinal, se ela não tiver um valor, o que você irá converter para inteiro?

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    int i;
    string a = "15";

    i = stoi(a);
}
```

Vejo no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/nZekJm).

Comment: Muitissismo obr pela explicação! Estou aprendendo c e c++ juntos, então confundo direto as coisas. Mas de verdade obr mesmo!
Tenho só uma pergunta aproveitando que vc comentou, nenhuma biblioteca tem o .h? todas eu posso só colocar o nome da biblioteca sem o .h? PS: esse código eu fiz como um exemplo do que eu iria fazer no programa real, no caso a string a tem valor.

Comment: @Gui_Reis, no caso do C, todos os headers das bibliotecas possuem `.h`. Em C++, as bibliotecas nativas não possuem as extensão `.h`, mas C++ também utiliza bibliotecas do C, então você precisa saber de antemão qual é o tipo da biblioteca que você está utilizando para saber se ela possui ou não essa extensão.

Comment: entendi, faz sentido! mT obr pela explicação