# Converter inteiro para string em C

Tags: c, string, conversão-de-tipo, inteiros

Tenho um problema com converter um inteiro para string no escopo de uma função onde o retorno da conversão é dado como nulo e eu não sei porque.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *getTexto(int num) {

    char numTxt[7];

    itoa(num, numTxt, 10);

    if ( num % 3 == 0 ) {
        if ( num % 5 == 0 ) {
            return "TicTac";
        }
        else {
            return "Tic";
        }
    }
    else if ( num % 5 == 0 ) {
        return "Tac";
    }
    else {
        return numTxt;
    }

}

int main() {

    for ( int x = 1; x <= 100; x++ ) {
        printf("\n%s", getTexto(x));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bom dia @Noronha, seja bem vindo, veja se isso te ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/436759/como-converter-string-para-int-em-c/436760#436760

Comment: vc pode simplificar removendo o ultimo `else` e deixar somete o `return numTxt`